# Animating a spritesheet on <canvas> WITHOUT a JS library

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, sprite-sheet

Good afternoon. As the title states, I am trying to animate a 2d spritesheet on a canvas element for a simple 2d game that I am making. I have gone through nearly a dozen articles and have not found what I am looking for, which is instructions on how to go about doing this without help from any sort of library. You might say to me, well sir, you are crazy if you aren't going to take advantage of this freely available technology that could make your life easier. My response to that is that I am doing this for the sake of learning, because I want to become a better javascript developer, and grow to write bigger and better games. That being said, I guess my question is: how do I animate a spritesheet? (I want the player to be able to input directions with the arrow keys) Make no mistake: I am not asking for anyone to write code for me, rather I am asking where I can find the resources to teach myself how to do this on my own. Thanks everyone, much appreciated.

Comment: Waw that's certainly a motivation :) Yes, this can be done as the `canvasRenderingContext2d.drawImage()` function takes up to 8 variables defining the size and position of the image and the size and position of the box that cuts it off. Takes a while to understand all the `dx, sx, sy, dy, sw, sh, dh, dw` correlations but otherwise that's what you need. Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage - Btw, kudos for the vanilla javascript approach. It teaches you a lot more about how programming works.

Comment: Alright, I took a look at the documentation that you linked in your comment. I was following it up until the parameters that define properties of the sub-rectangle. It would be awesome if you could clarify what purpose that sub-rectangle serves. Now that I know how to draw an image, how do I go about animating it?

Comment: I'd love to, but I have barely scrapped that surface myself. It really takes some getting used to but I'm sure if you have some time this can be figured out by playing with it... Also, I sadly don't have time to experiment and provide you with a good answer. I did upvote in the hope you'll attract someone who fluently speaks `drawImage` :)

Comment: Well that is very kind of you :) Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: canvas + RequestAnimationFrame. Here a great tutorial: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/

I was looking for an html5 + javascript 2d game project to join months ago. If you're interested I would like to collaborate with you on this project. Just let me know and enjoy the tutorial

You can create a simple animation loop creating a canvas in your html document:

```
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

This will be your "game board"

Then you can create a javascript file in where defining the game engine.
You can load an external image inside an image element like this:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "my-sprite-animation.png";
```

And defining a sprite:

```
var mySprite = sprite({
  context: canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  image: coinImage
});
```

Then using the requestAnimationFrame method for creating an animation loop:

```
function gameLoop () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop); 
  mySprite.update();
  mySprite.render();
}
```

Comment: I'm reading through that tutorial now. Sure, I think that collaborating on a 2d game could be a pretty good learning experience for the both of us. Truth be told, I'm a college student, and I've never collaborated on a project like this. I would love to discuss more and find out your ideas on how we would go about that.

Comment: Sure, my github is Azurasky1.

Comment: Ok, send me an email with some information about this project

Comment: I'm not too clear on private messaging on there so I'm gonna send you an email, look out for a new message in your inbox

Comment: @SonnY. Your link is on-point and useful :-), but "link only" answers are frowned upon here on Stackoverflow because if the link rots then the answer becomes useless. To make a proper answer, you should describe how to clip & display individual sprites from the spritesheet using `requestAnimationFrame`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @markE but the question was about what kind of technology to use for animate a sprite using javascript and I explained that in my reply. I also included an extra link containing an interesting tutorial

Comment: Hmmm...if your answer is "use canvas + requestAnimationFrame" then your answer is, IMO, too vague to be useful. Therefore, I'm downvoting your answer. If you edit your answer to provide more usable info then ping me and I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: @markE, I implemented more "juice" to my answer, I hope this will now satisfy your standards. I'm just trying to help people here and I'm really not going to waste hours of my time writing tutorial, those are already around the Internet. What people need to know here is a guideline and simple answers, not tutorials